# Android how to increase height and width of star in ratingbar

Tags: android, widget, android-styles, rating, ratingbar

I am implementing `ratingbar` and I want to set `ratingbar` like below attached image but the problem is that when I use `match_parent` of `ratingbar` width then more than five star show in `ratingbar`. Can anyone help me how to implement my rating bar as attached image or suggest me how to implement it.
Here is my activity_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="gymtrainer.com.ratinbarexample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Rate 5 star for RatingBar"
        />


    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        style="@style/foodRatingBar"
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar_default"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.1"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="show state up checkbox"
        android:textColor="#CC00CC"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Main Activity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RatingBar ratingbar1;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButtonClick();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButtonClick(){

        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        final RatingBar ratingBar_default = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_default);

        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ratingBar_default.setRating(5);
                text.setText("Rating: "+String.valueOf(ratingBar_default.getRating()));
            }
        });

        ratingBar_default.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text.setText("Rating: "+String.valueOf(rating));
            }});
    }
}
```

Here is my style

```
 <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">100dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">100dip</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Android won't scale the icon. So Simply use your custom icon and set `minHeight` and `maxHeight` accroding to that.

Comment: i use custom library compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.0.10'

Comment: @ amorenew  Thanks for help me. Is it not possible to do this thing without any library ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use a RatingBar different to the Android's default, I'm the creator of: [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors in normal state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable colors in pressed state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Customizable stars corner radius.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

You can find it either in `jcenter` or in `Maven Central`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`

In your example, you can use it as:

```
<com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar_default"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
        app:srb_stepSize="0.1"
        app:srb_starSize="100dp"
        app:srb_borderColor="@color/your_light_green_color"
        app:srb_fillColor="@color/your_light_green_color"
        />
```

No extra xml files needed :)

I hope it's useful.